# How to find the range in $f(x)=\left|\frac{(\tan 6x+\tan 2x)(\cos 3x + \cos x )}{(\sin 6x)}\right|$ given a boundary for $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, maxima-minima

The problem is as follows:

> Let the function:
>
> $f(x)=\left|\frac{(\tan 6x+\tan 2x)(\cos 3x + \cos x )}{(\sin 6x)}\right|$
>
> Assume $x\in \left\langle \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{4\pi}{9}\right]-\left\{\frac{\pi}{3}\right]$
>
> Find the maximum value which can take $f(x)$, using range analysis. Assume $f(x)$ gives values measured in hundreds of units.
>
> The choices given in my workbook are as follows:
>
> $\begin{array}{ll}
> 1.&195\\
> 2.&198\\
> 3.&199\\
> 4.&200\\
> \end{array}$

I'm really lost at how should I solve this problem. Since the problem indicates that this should be solved relying only in range analysis the thing is I don't know how to find the range for that function in the given:

$x\in \left\langle \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{4\pi}{9}\right]-\left\{\frac{\pi}{3}\right]$

Thus I require help here. The only thing which I do recall is that absolute value will add a negative sign in front of whatever thing is inside if it is less than zero. Thus I believe that should be used here to see if it will have this sign in front for those functions in the given boundary for $x$. But I don't know how to use these ideas together.

I'm not sure if the multiplication of those function should be treated as intersection or what?. I'm confused as I explained how to get the range. As this problem is presented in my precalculus workbook thus an answer using such approach is the one which I'm intending to find.

Can someone guide me on **what to do** please, the answer which would help me the most is one which does explain **step by step** so I don't get confused with the solution. Thus, can this be solved without much fuss?.

Comment: My first step would be to get down in the mud.
Let $x \in \{(\pi/4 + \delta), (\pi/3 - \delta), (\pi/3 + \delta), (4\pi/9)\},~~$
where it is understood that $\delta$ will represent some small (as yet
unspecified) positive amount.  Examine $f(x)$ for each of these points.
Then, examining the data, attempt to form a hypothesis that answers the
question.  Then attempt to prove the hypothesis.  Regardless of how
far you get, edit your query to show all of your work.  Please do
**not** respond with a comment.

Comment: With respect to the mathSE protocol of you showing your work, see [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933), and, more generally, [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: What do all the different bracket types you used mean? I've only ever come across $[$ and $($ types before.

Comment: Also try to simplify the things inside the bracket. Expand the numerator , write $\tan$ as $\frac{\sin}{\cos}$ , use the formula $\sin(3x)=3\sin(x)-4\sin^3x$ and $\cos(3x)=4\cos^3x-3\cos(x)$ and it simplifies the function. If I've calculated it correctly, I get $f(x)=\left | \frac{4\cos(x).\sin(8x)}{\sin(12x)} \right |$ and now I'm trying to think of a way to find its range without calculus.

Comment: If you decide to pursue the approach of my first comment, and are having trouble using the $\delta$ analogy, and if you happen to have a calculator (or some other way of computing trig functions for arbitrary values), simply choose an arbitrary value for $x$ that is slightly larger than $(\pi/4)$, an arbitrary value that is slightly smaller than $(\pi/3)$, and an arbitrary value that is slightly larger than $(\pi/3)$, and then use the calculator to carefully compute $f(x)$ for these values.